# React Native - Use context from a non-component function

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-hooks

I tried to set up translation for my app.

I keep the translations in a json file:

```
{
  "en": {
    "tenSeconds": "Ten Seconds",
    "skipQuestion": "Skip Question",
    "doubleDip": "Double Dip",
    "fiftyFifty": "Fifty Fifty"
  },
  "tr": {
    "tenSeconds": "On Saniye",
    "skipQuestion": "Soruyu Geç",
    "doubleDip": "Çifte Cevap",
    "fiftyFifty": "Yarı Yarıya"
  }
}
```

I have a context to get the current language from:

```
import React, {useState, createContext, useEffect} from 'react';
import AsyncStorage from '@react-native-async-storage/async-storage';

import {LANGUAGE_EN, LANGUAGE_STORAGE_KEY} from '../constants';

const defaultLanguage = LANGUAGE_EN;

export const LanguageContext = createContext();

export const LanguageProvider = (props) => {
  const [language, setLanguage] = useState(defaultLanguage);

  useEffect(() => {
    (async () => {
      const storedLanguage = await getStoredLanguage();

      setLanguage(storedLanguage);
    })();
  }, []);

  const getStoredLanguage = async () => {
    try {
      const value = await AsyncStorage.getItem(LANGUAGE_STORAGE_KEY);
      if (value !== null) {
        return value;
      } else {
        return defaultLanguage;
      }
    } catch (err) {
      console.log(err);
    }
  };

  return (
    <LanguageContext.Provider value={[language, setLanguage]}>
      {props.children}
    </LanguageContext.Provider>
  );
};
```

and I have a translator function that takes the language and key of the translation string and returns the translation:

```
import {useContext} from 'react';

import {LanguageContext} from '../contexts/LanguageContext';
import strings from '../assets/values/strings.json';

const t = (language, translationKey) => {
  // const [language] = useContext(LanguageContext); // can't use this here

  return strings[language][translationKey];
};

export default t;
```

I use it like this:

```
const TestComponent = () => {
  const [language] = useContext(LanguageContext);

  return <Text>{t(language, 'tenSeconds')}</Text>;
};
```

The problem is, every time I need to use it, I need to get language from the context and use it with the translator function. The ideal thing to do would be to use it like `t('tenSeconds')` and eliminate the need for importing language context from every component that I need translation instead.

I tried to get the language from the context in the translator function but React does not let me do that because it's not a component. Is there any sort of trick for what I'm trying to do here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like a use case for a [custom hook](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-custom.html#using-a-custom-hook):

```
// useTranslator.js
export const useTranslator = () => {
  const [language] = useContext(LanguageContext);
  return (arg) => t(language, arg);
};

// Test.js
import {useTranslator} from 'useTranslator.js';

const TestComponent = () => {
  const translator = useTranslator();

  return <Text>{translator("tenSeconds")}</Text>;
};
```